# Work abroad while living on the US under H4 Visa

Tags: usa, h4-visa

I just arrived to the States a couple months ago under H4 visa, I work in oil and gas and have a opportunity to apply for a commuter/rotational position in the middle east, I know I am not allowed to work in the US but what that position offers me is going to ME for 30 days and then come back to the States for 30 days on days off... Is that legal? Can I ask them to pay me here in the States or they need to pay me in my homecountry?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are only in H4 status when you are in the US. The US has no conditions on what you do when you are not in the US.